# How to make a js script Never executed by google bots

Tags: javascript, googlebot

I have a small script which job is to change dynamically some letters in the titles of a web page. (It is done for graphic purposes, those letters are set in a "iconized" font, it's pretty nice ^^).

The problem is, Google indexes the page with the modified letters, and my content is full of words with bad letters ie. `HELLO WFRLD`

Is there any way to make a js script not executable by google bots ?
I was thinking something like;

```
if(!window.googlebot && navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' GOOGLE/') !) {
    //script
}
```

Do you have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: use robots.txt to block out the js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In robots.txt

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: maybeYourFile.js
Disallow: .js
```